# How to detect iPhone 6 plus with native API?

Tags: iphone

How to detect iPhone 6 plus with native API? (without checking a screen resolution)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Targeting a specific device is usually not the right way to develop things.

Comment: @StephenDarlington, for example, Contacts.app looks different in landscape mode. iPhone 6 displays only detail view, but iPhone 6 Plus displays master and detail views. [The Verge demo](http://www.theverge.com/2014/9/9/6124931/apple-iphone-6-plus-hands-on-video-photos-5-5)

Comment: Check out the "Building adaptive interfaces" session from WWDC (session 216). You mostly use size classes and auto layout. You _don't_ need to know the type of device.

Answer (score 3):

In general you don't need to know which device you're running on. If you need specific hardware features then you can add them to your Info.plist.

If you want to know about the screen size then the correct way of doing it is to use the new size classes feature in iOS 8. You can see more details in the "Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit" talk at WWDC.

This also allows you to do things like show a popover on an iPad or iPhone 6 and a modal view on other devices. And you don't need to worry if Apple comes out with a new screen size.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect iPhone 6 Plus based on its native scale, using this macro:

```
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_6PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale] == 3.0f)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return true if iPhone 6 Plus called **Retina HD 5.5** by Apple.

```
-(BOOL)iPhone6Plus{
    if (([UIScreen mainScreen].scale > 2.0)) return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to detect that it's definitely an iPhone 6 Plus (or any other iOS device):

https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/UIDevice-Hardware/blob/master/UIDevice%2BHardware.m